# Error received when creating a table on sqlite (android)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a table on sqlite. I have more than 30 tables created, but this command doesn't seem to work.

```
private final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION = "create table " + TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION
        + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," + COLUMN_EVENT_NAME + " text , "
        + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + "  integer , " + COLUMN_DETECTION_TIMESTAMP + "  integer , "
        + COLUMN_RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP + "  integer , " + COLUMN_SERVER_STATUS + " integer)";
```

This is the command I'm running :

```
database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION);
```

But, I'm receiving an exception, and it looks like the TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION is an empty string - which it isn't.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table (id integer primary key autoincrement,event_name text , timestamp  integer , detection_timestamp  integer , received_timestamp  integer , server_status integer)
```

Fully code :

```
public class NSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = NSQLiteOpenHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // Database
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 50;

    // Tables
    public static final String TABLE_NODES = "nodes";
    public static final String TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION = "events_collection_log"; //Logging all the events received and sending it to the server.

    // Columns - Common (TABLE NODES)
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PAGE_ID = "page_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String COLUMN_NEURA_ID = "neura_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NODE_DATA = "node_data";
    public static final String COLUMN_SENT_TO_SERVER = "sent";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_PATH = "image_path";
    public static final String COLUMN_SERVER_STATUS = "server_status";
    public static final String COLUMN_SERVER_RESPONSE_CODE = "server_response_code";
    public static final String COLUMN_SERVER_RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP = "server_response_timestamp";
    public static final String COLUMN_SERVER_LAST_UPDATE = "server_last_update";
    public static final String COLUMN_PENDING = "pending";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTHENTICATION_URL = "auth_url";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENDOR = "vendor";
    public static final String COLUMN_NODE_IMAGE_SYNC_TO_SERVER = "image_sync_to_serve";
    public static final String COLUMN_NODE_TYPE = "node_type";
    public static final String COLUMN_RELATED_NODE_ID = "related_node_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_IS_ME = "isMe";

    // Columns (TABLE_DEVICES)
    public static final String COLUMN_DEVICE_ID = "device_id";

    // Columns (TABLE LIFELINE ITEMS)
    public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String COLUMN_DETECTION_TIMESTAMP = "detection_timestamp";
    public static final String COLUMN_RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP = "received_timestamp";

    public static final String COLUMN_EVENT_NAME = "event_name";

    private final String CREATE_TABLE_NODES = "create table " + TABLE_NODES + "(" + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_VENDOR + " text, " + COLUMN_NODE_TYPE
            + " text, " + COLUMN_PAGE_ID + " integer ," + COLUMN_TYPE + " integer ,"
            + COLUMN_NEURA_ID + " text UNIQUE ," + COLUMN_NODE_DATA + " text ," + COLUMN_PENDING
            + " integer, " + COLUMN_SENT_TO_SERVER + " integer, " + COLUMN_DEVICE_ID + " text, "
            + COLUMN_IMAGE_PATH + " text, " + COLUMN_NODE_IMAGE_SYNC_TO_SERVER + " integer, "
            + COLUMN_AUTHENTICATION_URL + " text, " + COLUMN_RELATED_NODE_ID + " text, "
            + COLUMN_SERVER_STATUS + " integer, " + COLUMN_SERVER_RESPONSE_CODE + " integer, "
            + COLUMN_SERVER_RESPONSE_TIMESTAMP + " integer, " + COLUMN_IS_ME + " integer, "
            + COLUMN_SERVER_LAST_UPDATE + " integer)";

    private final String CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION = "create table " + TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION
            + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," + COLUMN_EVENT_NAME + " text , "
            + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + "  integer , " + COLUMN_DETECTION_TIMESTAMP + "  integer , "
            + COLUMN_RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP + "  integer , " + COLUMN_SERVER_STATUS + " integer)";

    public NSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NODES);
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> your TABLE_EVENTS_COLLECTION is empty after **create table** there is no table name.

```
create table "Your_Table_Name"(id integer primary key autoincrement,event_name text , timestamp  integer , detection_timestamp  integer , received_timestamp  integer , server_status integer)
```

Comment: Hi @Moubeen, thanks for the response, but.. I don't understand, it's not empty, I do the same for 30 other tables ! whats the difference there ? If I add the table as just a string, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @HadasM It seems to be correct I also Do Like what your are doing, but i have get that error before in your onCreate Write a log statement and check if you are getting the correct create statement.